# Is the TMap next book from 2006 still aligned with nowadays IT?

Tags: test-design, tmap

In 2009 I was following a workshop about QA and received the TMap next book:

[image]

Now I would like to know more about testing and would like to know whether this book is still aligned with nowadays IT.

On Amazon several newer books were found including:

- [https://www.amazon.com/End-end-testing-TMap-Next/dp/9072194969/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1492766884&sr=8-2&keywords=tmap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9072194969)
- [https://www.amazon.com/TMap-Next-Business-Driven-Managament/dp/9072194934/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1492766884&sr=8-3&keywords=tmap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9072194934)

[TMap's official website](http://www.tmap.net/) indicates that:

> TMap is Sogeti’s prominent testing approach since 1995. Keeping up
>   with changing businesses and technology, TMap has now developed into
>   the TMap Suite. The TMap Suite is thé body of knowledge for
>   professional testing of today and tomorrow. The items of our TMap
>   Suite give you all the guidance you need to meet the testing and
>   quality challenges in your specific information technology
>   environment.
>
> The latest addition to the TMap Suite is TMap HD - Human Driven. This
>   approach to testing is quality driven to meet with the challenges of
>   modern, agile organizations. TMap HD is described in the novel “Neil’s
>   Quest for Quality”.

The link to TMap indicates that the latest version of the books dates from 2014, but no overview was found of differences between certain versions.

Answer (score 2):

There is some useful and relevant information but it is very high level and seems a bit dated.

This is just before Agile starting sweeping through the development world and as a result, seems to focus more on checking after things have been built - the traditonal role of 'QA', rather than the 'prevent errors in the first place by being embedded in the development teamn' approach that has become widely (though not universally) accepted as a good development practice in the Agile Development world that now dominates application development (based on survey at large nationwide software development conferences - Techwell, Star, etc.)

Does provide free excel checklists that have some good ideas.

Answer (score 2):

The original TMap and it's 2006 update TMap Next are tomes that contain an enormous amount of information, plus nine hundred pages of them. This is overwhelming and time consuming to digest. Especially if you try to figure out how the information can be used in your current project and in the current and still changing big world of IT.

Instead of burrying yourself in the big book, try the following:

Read these two books first:
+ Neil's quest for quality, an easy to read and very recognizable story,
  I also found it an enjoyable book.
+ TMap Next Business Driven Test Management, in essence a summary of
  the big book but with focus on business aspects, this is still relevant.

This creates the base knowledge needed to understand the big book.
From there on you can use the tome for further reference, to decipher the content and select what is still in use, to become conscious of what has changed over the years due to new technology and new insights. To find the ways to make the concepts work for your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Today (27th of July) I found out that another book 
has been published by Sogeti in april 2016.

The title is:

> IoTMap testing in an IoT environment

*by Tom van de Ven, Jaap Bloem and Jean-Pascal Duniau, 168 pages*
(IoT = internet of things).

Available in paperback and as an E-book.

Still have to order and read it, but it sounds promising
as a modern step in the application of the TMap method.